# Сложение доп. кода на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Необходимо выполнить операцию сложения двух целых чисел в дополнительном коде результат разместить в регистре BX. Числа для опыта : -7 и -259 (десятичные)

Вот что я пытался сделать

```
PAGE 60,132
TITLE Z1(.COM)
;
CODESG SEGMENT PARA 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CODESG, DS:CODESG, SS:CODESG, ES:CODESG
;
ORG 100H
BEGIN PROC NEAR
mov ax,-7
mov bx,-259
add ax,bx
INT 21H
;
BEGIN ENDP
CODESG ENDS
END BEGIN
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: добавил свое решение, но не уверен что оно правильное поскольку складываю обычные числа а не дополнительный код этих чисел. как с ним быть?

Comment: @user280646, ассемблер сам превращает числа в дополнительный код. Никаких дополнительных действий для этого не нужно делать. Только чтобы результат сложения оказался в регистре bx, нужно делать `add bx,ax` вместо `add ax,bx`

Comment: получается, мое решение является верным?

Comment: Про результат в BX дописал в комментарии выше, а так верно.